# iOS launch screen show wrong image resources

Tags: ios, xcode, launch-screen

My app has modified the launch screen on this version. and the previous version of my app was uploaded already on App Store.

And I found something strange during the ready to deploy this version.

This is the process that I found the problem.

1. Deleted the debug mode app(It is confirmed that the launch screen was updated well).
2. Installed the previous version of my app from App Store.
3. Reinstalled the new version from TestFlight or Xcode.
4. Found the issue that the image resources of launch screen are previous version's.

Why is this? and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try restart your device

Comment: @Tj3n I already cleaned the project and restarted Xcode and device. so my app hadn't problem before testing with App Store. I'm just worried about existing production users who will not restart own device when update my app from App Store. If this problem not affect to production users, I don't have to care. but I'm not sure.

Comment: I had a similar problem, the only dirty fix I could find was renaming the image resources. Instead of launch.png it's launch1.png and not mistakingly opening the old image resource if it is still there for some reason. Therefore, it's not looking for launch.png. Definitely not the best, but I couldn't find any solution at the time.

Answer (score 0):

delete your app on your device. and restart your device. if you install apps from Xcode.try to restart your Xcode too. then reinstall the app.

Comment: I already cleaned the project and restarted Xcode and device. so my app hadn't problem before testing with App Store. I'm just worried about existing production users who will not restart own device when update my app from App Store. If this problem not affect to production users, I don't have to care. but I'm not sure.